# Jquery code to append values to json array and check values are equal or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Am using following code to push values to JSON array

```
var schedule = [];
myArray = [ { Tests: [ [Object] ],
    _id: '52bd60d72270a398d3f87302',
    browser: [ 'FF' ],
    id: '71',
    mode: 'weekly',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
    server: '172.16.2.120' },
  { Tests: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    _id: '52c247f1cf0060b8cce84b42',
    browser: [ 'FF' ],
    id: '45',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
    server: '172.16.2.120' },
  { _id: '52ca2b0dafcec877d925d111',
    Tests: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    browser: [ 'FF', 'IE' ],
    id: '37',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-32',
    server: '172.16.2.120' } ];
```

While calling `execute` first time myArray contain 1 value.I have to call execute function based on the `myArray` values.if it contains 4 values it will call four times like wise.and append the `myArray` values to schedule array inside execute function

```
execute(myArray ){
schedule.push(myArray );
}
```

What I have to do inside `execute` function is to check the `os` values with each other and detect they are equal or not?if equal I have to perform some task other wise another task how it is possible?

Comment: you want to compare all 3 os values are same in myArray or how do you want to perform this comparsion?

Comment: yes i have to compare the os are equal or not.first one is os: 'VM-WIN7-64',and campare this to second and third to check equal or not.also second to first one and third one wise vere.

Comment: What does `schedule` have to contain after all?

Answer (score 1):

`myArray` in your code is wrongly represented as `string` datatype.  so remove ' `quotes`.

```
execute(myArray ){
  $.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
    //now you have access to each elements so perform your comparsion
    console.log(myArray[index]['os'])    
   });
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UdLE6/)

Comment: @Sush check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UdLE6/1/ if your array is non-growing then above fiddle is fine